# Room database, SELECT * FROM table by a given day

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm using [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) in my Android project, and store date using [date type converter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter.html):

```
object DateConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? = if (null == value) null else Date(value)

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? = date?.time
}
```

How could I select from my table by a given **day** using using [Room DAO](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data.html)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date BETWEEN :dayst AND :dayet")
 Object getFromTable(long dayst, long dayet);
```

date `dayst` will be the timestamp for 00:00, i.e., `09/11/2017 00:00:00`

date `dayet` will be the timestamp for 23:59, i.e., `09/11/2017 23:59:59`

The `Object` is what you are getting from the database.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want particular Date, I want particular day. Two entries inserted with 1 minute interval will have different Date (i.e. long date timestamp) but will have the same day.

Comment: It works, thanks! But you can refactor this a little bit. Since I'm using type converter there is no need to pass long values to the Dao, I can use Date object.

Comment: Cool, @JanSlominski. Refactor it the way it best fits your needs ;)

Comment: I mean the whole point of date converter (and Room type converters in general) is not to pass timestamps as Long or String, but use Date objects (which can't be stored in SQLite without conversion).

Comment: I think the type converters are to be used to save and read the info in the database, but I am not sure that when you are searching the info directly in the database if it should be in the format that you saved it in. The best way to know it is to try it both ways :D

Answer (score 1):

make it more simple.

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date BETWEEN :daystart AND :dayend")
List<Student> fetchAllData(long start,long end);
```

Comment: date is column name

Answer (score 1):

I have taken value of day, month and year by spinner. 
You can use it(With string and DateTypeConvertor instead Long) like this

At Dao :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM MILKMANTABLE WHERE strftime('%Y',date) IN(:year) AND strftime('%m',date) IN(:month) AND strftime('%d',date) IN(:day)")

List<MilkMan> getMonthDetails(String day, String month, String year);
```

You can use this converter class to convert and save Date type to string in room table

```
DateTypeConverter :

public class DateConverter {
    static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DOB_FORMAT);

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date fromTimestamp(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            try {
                return df.parse(value);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String dateToTimestamp(Date value) {

        return value == null ? null : df.format(value);
    }
}
```

At Constants.java:

```
public static String DOB_FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-dd";
```