# Can I get Data From Room Query Like in Pair<loan_amount,adv_interest_amount>?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

**I know that I can do that by using data class but I want to achieve Like this**

````
// This is My Query

    @Query("SELECT loan_amount,adv_interest_amount FROM new_pledge_receive WHERE (new_pledge_receive.bill_date BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate)")
    fun getPledgeReceiveAmount(fromDate: Long,toDate: Long):LiveData<List<Pair<Double,Double>>> ```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47199783/9792247 try this may be it will help.

Comment: I know I can do Like that but can I do like above mentioned query

Comment: You have to create new model class for this two variables `loan_amount, adv_interest_amount` and pass into `LiveData<>`

Comment: I already mention that ** I know how to do it by using data class , My Question is can I do like that or not**

Answer (score 4):

Pair class has 2 properties: `first` and `second`. Try to set the name of the selected columns to fit these names.

Something like: `SELECT my_custom_field as first, my_another_field as second FROM...`

Comment: does this work? failed on my case. maybe because of Pair class.

Comment: @guness what does the exception say?

Comment: don't remember exact error, but it was like unable to find a converter from cursor to pair which I had and annotated already. tried with different types of Pairs from different packages, all same. Then end up with custom Tuple object.

Comment: It is probably based on how Room transforms the query result into LiveData<>. What converter did you make so far? Can you attach it to the question or any other way?

Comment: it was like:

    @TypeConverter
    fun toPair(cursor: Cursor?): Pair<String, Boolean>? {
        ....
    }

Comment: @guness I think Type converters are not working in LiveData. I suggest to change return type of the `getPledgeReceiveAmount` to `Pair<String, Boolean>` and create LiveData in the caller of it. Type converter is not used here.

Comment: I have tried returning Observable<List<Pair<String,Boolean>>>
as well as List and simple Pair only as well, just did not work in any case.

Answer (score -1):

As they mention on the [official website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Query)

> For SELECT queries, Room will infer the result contents from the method's return type and generate the code that will automatically convert the query result into the method's return type. For single result queries, the return type can be any java object. For queries that return multiple values, you can use List or Array. In addition to these, any query may return Cursor or any query result can be wrapped in a LiveData.