# Android Room Type Converter for Cursor -> List

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to write a type converter for a `List<Pair<Uri,Uri?>>`:

```
Query("SELECT $uri, $imageUrl FROM $data WHERE $color IS NULL")
abstract fun findWithMissingColor(): List<Pair<Uri, Uri?>>
```

```
@TypeConverter
fun toUriPair(cursor: Cursor?): List<Pair<Uri, Uri?>> {
    return cursor?.let{ generateSequence { if (it.moveToNext()) it else null }.map {
         Pair(
                Uri.parse(it.getString(0)),
                try { Uri.parse(it.getString(1)) } catch (e: Exception) {null}
         )
    }.toList() } ?: emptyList()
}
```

which is loosely based on information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57735875/can-i-get-data-from-room-query-like-in-pairloan-amount-adv-interest-amount).

But Room doesn't recognize this as a valid type converter for this query:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.util.List<kotlin.Pair<android.net.Uri,android.net.Uri>>).
    public abstract java.util.List<kotlin.Pair<android.net.Uri, android.net.Uri>> findWithMissingColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

The core principal of the answer you used as the basis is that if more than 1 column is extracted that the column names match (duplicate column names are ambiguous):-

> Room will automatically bind the parameters of the method into the bind arguments. This is done by matching the name of the parameters to the name of the bind arguments.

- [Query](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Query)

Additionally a TypeConverter can only convert a single value :-

> Each converter method should receive 1 parameter and have non-void return type

- [TypeConverter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/TypeConverter)

**EXAMPLE**

Without going into the possibility that you may have serialised URI's and URL's, here's an example that may assist with you extracting the data, assuming that the URI's and URL's are plain Strings. i.e. no need for TypeConverters. Would obviously be different if using serialised URI's and URL's and BLOBS. Then you need a TypeConverters for each

The example is based upon what has been included in your question but as explained may well differ.

**MyDataPair** (an inner class of **MyDataEntity**) is the equivalent of the tuple/Pair with member names of **first** and **second** these being important as the column names when extract have to match these names (first point made above).

First the Entity which I've called **MyDataEntity** (this will probably differ but is basically the structure bar String V Blob) :-

```
@Entity(tableName = MyDataEntity.MYTABLE_TABLE_NAME)
class MyDataEntity{

    /*
        CONSTANTS for COLUMN AND TABLE NAMES
     */
    companion object {
        const val ID_COLUMN_NAME: String = "_id"
        const val URI_COLUMN_NAME: String = "uri"
        const val IMAGEURL_COLUMN_NAME: String = "urlimage"
        const val COLOR_COLUMN_NAME: String = "color"
        const val MYTABLE_TABLE_NAME: String = "mydata"
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = ID_COLUMN_NAME)
    var id: Long? = null
    @ColumnInfo(name = URI_COLUMN_NAME)
    var uri: String? = null
    @ColumnInfo(name = IMAGEURL_COLUMN_NAME)
    var imageUrl: String? = null
    @ColumnInfo(name = COLOR_COLUMN_NAME)
    var color: Long? = null

    constructor()

    @Ignore
    constructor(id: Long?,uri: String?,imageurl: String,color: Long?) {
        this.id = id
        this.uri = uri
        this.imageUrl = imageurl
        this.color = color
    }

    class MyDataPair(first: String?, second: String?) {
        var first: String? = first
        var second: String? = second

        @Ignore
        /* NOT USED/COMPLETE */
        fun getFirstAsUri(): URI {
            /* code here to build URI */
            return URI(first)
        }
        @Ignore
        /* NOT USED/COMPLETE */
        fun getSecondAsUrl(): URL {
            /* code here to build URL */
            return URL(second)
        }
    }
}
```

The Dao **MyDataDao** (including your query AND specific output column names to suit the inner **MyDataPair** class (first and Second) in the MyDataEntity) :-

```
@Dao
interface MyDataDao {

    /* For inserting test data */
    @Insert
    fun insertMyDataRow(myDataEntity: MyDataEntity): Long
    /* Efectively your query BUT WITH specific output/result column names to suit the MyDataPair class */
    @Query("SELECT ${MyDataEntity.URI_COLUMN_NAME} AS first,${MyDataEntity.IMAGEURL_COLUMN_NAME} AS second FROM ${MyDataEntity.MYTABLE_TABLE_NAME} WHERE ${MyDataEntity.COLOR_COLUMN_NAME} IS NULL")
    fun findWithMissingColor(): List<MyDataEntity.MyDataPair>
    /* Clear the table for renability */
    @Query("DELETE FROM ${MyDataEntity.MYTABLE_TABLE_NAME}")
    fun clearMyDataEntityTable(): Int
}
```

The Database **MyDatabase**

```
@Database(entities = [MyDataEntity::class],version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getMyDataDao(): MyDataDao
    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase"
    }
}
```

Finally an Activity **MainActivity** putting it all together :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: MyDatabase
    lateinit var dao: MyDataDao
    val TAG = "MYDBINFO"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,MyDatabase::class.java,MyDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
        dao = db.getMyDataDao()
        var deleted_rows = dao.clearMyDataEntityTable()

        /* CLEAR ANY EXIST DATALOAD AND LOAD SOME DATA */
        Log.d(TAG, "$deleted_rows were deleted from the table ${MyDataEntity.MYTABLE_TABLE_NAME}")
        dao.insertMyDataRow(MyDataEntity(null,"uri1","imageurl1", 0x00ffffff))
        dao.insertMyDataRow(MyDataEntity(null,"uri2","imageurl2",null))
        dao.insertMyDataRow(MyDataEntity(null,"uri3","imageurl3",0xAAAAAA))
        dao.insertMyDataRow(MyDataEntity(null,"uri4","imageurl4",null))
        /* EXTRACT ROWS WHERE COLOR IS NULL */
        var results = dao.findWithMissingColor()
        /* WRITE SOME INFO ABOUT THE EXTRACTED DATA TO THE LOG */
        for(mdp: MyDataEntity.MyDataPair in results) {
            Log.d(TAG,"STRING_URI =  ${mdp.first}  STRING_URL = ${mdp.second}")
        }
    }
}
```

- runs of the main thread for convenience and brevity
- inserts 4 rows 2 with color as NULL, 2 with a color

**RESULTS** from a run

The database after running is (as per Database Inspector) :-

[image]

The Log includes :-

```
2021-04-12 12:29:18.085 D/MYDBINFO: 4 were deleted from the table mydata
2021-04-12 12:29:18.099 D/MYDBINFO: STRING_URI =  uri2  STRING_URL = imageurl2
2021-04-12 12:29:18.099 D/MYDBINFO: STRING_URI =  uri4  STRING_URL = imageurl4
```